# The URL will be appended with a question mark as the user press enter

Tags: javascript, forms, input, keyboard, keycode

I have an `input` tag within a `form`, when I press enter in the input box. The `url` will be appended with a question mark.

code:

```
<form>
    <input id="xyz" type="text" value="">                                       
</form>
```

This is very annoying, so I add some code to prevent the user from doing this behaviour. I change the body tag to:

```
<body onkeydown="(event.keyCode==13) ? 0 : 1">
```

Well, this works in another webpage, but not in this case.

What have I missed?

And is this a good solution to prevent user from pressing enter on the keyboard?

Please give some explanation in your answer, thanks.

p.s.  I can't use jQuery.

**UPDATE:** I don't want the user to enter press on their keyboard to submit a form even I define the form action and method.

Answer (score 1):

The default action when you press enter while in an input is to submit the form. Since you don't have any action defined for the form, it doesn't do anything. You also don't have a method defined so I believe it defaults to GET which uses parameters in the URL (like example.com?param1=abc&param2=123).

If you change `<form>` to `<form method="post">`that should stop the question mark from appearing. Though it's still not valid HTML because you don't have an action or a name for your form.

May I ask *why* you don't want them submitting the form when they press enter?

Comment: Well, actually the user doesn't really submit something to server when they press enter in this case. I want to remove the `form` tag, but my colleague disagree with it... In other pages, the default design wishes the user not to press the enter key to submit form. (My supervisor's wish)